# JQuery: Insert HTML into corresponding selectors using custom .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, find

To help demostrate what I am after, consider the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5TNVK/4/

Except I want it to only inject the HTML in the corresponding selector, not every selector. 
What I am attempting to do is have each selector match up with itself. On each ajax request, I get about 5 elements from the page I am loading and then animations and such with them. Currently I am first doing an ajax call then loop through an array of selectors assigning each html() the results of find(). This is very fast in all non-IE browsers, but takes about 1000 ms or more in IE8 when only finding 5 elements.

I figure there is an easier way that will ajax GET the page **once**, .find() every selector send to it and then insert the results to the same selector. Also it should only callback **once**.

I can't seem to grasp how to actually loop through each `self`. I would also want it so I just insert a url without the trailing selectors. The function would already know which selectors to use in `.find()` because it would be the same that were passed to it.

Ideally this is how it would work:

`$('#foo, .bar, #test[href=moo]').my_load('newpage.html');`

Where the current page's element with id=foo gets injected with newpage.html's element with id=foo, and the same for class=bar, etc.

Edit:

After some more benchmarking and such, it seems the .find() method is what is causing IE8 to be so slow in 1.4.4. finding 5 elements one by one in 3k html takes 1000ms in 1.4.4, in 1.3.2 it takes around 600ms.

Edit 2:

Keeping the way I had it before where I actually get the HTML source beforehand, I am using this function to parse the html source and get the selectors. This runs in about 200 ms in IE. So thats an improvement but I've been told to beware of innerHTML.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    super_load: function(html,callback ) {
        var self = this;

        var htmls = $(html).find(self.selector);

        for (var i =0; i < self.length; i++){
            self[i].innerHTML = htmls[i].innerHTML;
        }

        if ( callback ) {
            callback.call(this,html);
        }

        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell what kind of selector is used here. If you are using a `class` based selector at the root it will be very slow in IE since it does not have `getElementsByClassName` method

Comment: They are all `id` based selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to write your own loader. Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5TNVK/5/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hdr = $('<div />').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net #header', function(){
        $('#name').html( hdr.find('#name').html() );
        $('.aiButton[id=login]').html( hdr.find('#login').html() );
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it runs multple finds, which is very slow in IE8 and Jquery 1.4.4.

Comment: The `find()` function shouldn't be slow, especially in this case because it is searching a cached object. Did you test it?